# export UTF-8 while initialising aws EC2 through user-data script

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, utf-8, amazon-ec2

I am deploying my code to AWS EC2. Based on the documentation, I can set up a script using the user data parameter of a new ec2 instance and the script will be executed at instance startup.

I am trying to set the Language of the ubuntu instance to UTF-8. I have here my script. However, this fails to set the language to UTF-8, though it works when I ran it directly from the command line.

```
#!/bin/bash 
set -e -x
sudo apt-get install awscli -y
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

[screenshot of aws console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EpZM.png)

Can someone enlighten me why and how i can potentially solve this? Thank you!

Comment: Those variables only exist for the amount of time that the user-data script is running. Setting environment variables that way doesn't persist them to the server in any way.

Comment: See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Locale#Changing_settings_permanently to set the system level locale, which all users will inherit

Comment: Im sorry for asking but how can i allow i best change the environment variables then?